# How to style ion-input in Angular/Ionic framework?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Angular 7 and Ionic 4 and I am trying to style a form which has many ion-inputs.

I've been trying a lot of CSS options, but nothing seems to work.

Right now, the ion-inputs I have are very large in height and I would like to make them look better, smaller.

I tried giving a class to the ion-inputs, hearing that it would be easier to modify the CSS like that, but it's not working.

This is how my **HTML** code for inputs looks like:

```html
<ion-item lines="none" class ="itemform">
   <ion-input  class ="inputClass" id = "nameInput" [(ngModel)]="name" 
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type = "text" placeholder = 
       "Package's Name" required>
   </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

And the **CSS** code:

```css
ion-input{
    --background: rgb(219,219,219);

}

.itemform {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    background: rgb(219, 219, 219);
    height: 10%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

The width can be changed to be a bit smaller, but the height has a default value (or a problem which I don't understand) and can't be resized.

I would like to understand why the height can't be changed and also how I can change it and make my `ion-input` look better.

Comment: Changing the padding top and bottom using the CSS properties `--padding-top` and `--padding-bottom` doesn't change the height?

Comment: I've tried with --padding-top, --padding-bottom and also padding-top, padding-bottom.. I can make it look bigger using padding-top, but making it smaller it's not working. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

the below css works fine for me

```
ion-input{
            border-radius: 10px !important;
            padding-right: 30px;
            font-size: 0.9em;
            border: 1px solid #f1f1f1 !important;
            --background: rgb(219,219,219) !important;
            /* height: 10%; */
            /* width: 41%; */
            max-width: 50vw; // this is applying perfectly
            max-height: 10vh;
        }
```

Comment: I will try your code in a bit and tell you if it works. But thank you a lot for your time anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Ionic v3 the shadow DOM is used so it's not possible to add your custom style. The official and recommended way to customize your component is using the CSS custom properties: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#css-custom-properties

you can also use the global css utilities: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities